# HTTPS subdomain redirecting pages to main domain

Tags: php, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm encountering a very weird issue with a clients website I built and maintain...

My main website is http://www.pr-infrared.com and the test website is http://test.pr-infrared.com

Both of them are separate websites. You'll see that the test website has a shopping cart in it that I'm working on integrating.

I recently installed a GeoTrust SSL certificate for the domain pr-infrared.com.

The issue I'm encountering is that when try to access the HTTPS version of the test site (by simply adding an HTTPS in front of it) you'll see that it brings up the live site instead (you can tell that it's the live site from viewing the source code and the absence of the cart, checkout, and account navigation in the upper right corner). I found out what it's doing is anytime you try to bring up an HTTPS page on the test site it instead pulls up the identical page from the LIVE website.

I have no idea why it's doing this let alone how to fix it. Any thoughts would be appreciated. I'm losing my mind trying to figure this out!

Comment: This could be an issue with your webserver configs. What webserver are you using? Are you doing domain-based virtual hosting?

Answer (score 0):

1) I see the certificate is issued to www.pr-infrared.com, not pr-infrared.com

2) If you're running apache, have you checked the site configuration (perhaps /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl) to see where the DocumentRoot is?

Answer (score 0):

`pr-infrared.com`, `www.pr-infrared.com` and `test.pr-infrared.com` use the same IP address. Your certificate is only valid for `pr-infrared.com` and `www.pr-infrared.com`.

You could in principle use this certificate for `test.pr-infrared.com` too during development (perhaps by adding an exception to your browser). However, the virtual host would still need to have the appropriate `ServerName` for it. It looks like you haven't configured your virtual hosts properly.